# In GoogleDocs App, file size is always 0 (zero) for google files (but non-native files like MS Word/Excel have non zero size

Tags: google-apps-script

var files = DocsList.getFolderById(release[index]).getFiles();

```
  for(i in files){
    /*** Title field ***/
     var title = "<a href=\""+files[i].getUrl()+"\">"+ files[i].getName() +"</a>";
    /*** Size field ***/
     var size = files[i].getSize();
    /*** Owner field ***/
     var owner = files[i].getOwner().toString().substring(0,files[i].getOwner().toString().indexOf('@'));
```

getSize always returns Zero (0) for google files (document, presentation, spreadsheet). But from the Google Drive Resources menu, I can find word count, character count....and for non-google files (i.e., Word or Excel) a size appears.

Here's the method syntax (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#getSize). Does size require some kind of substring or tostring? what else do I need to add?

Comment: I suspect this is because they're not strictly speaking 'files' per-se  - they have a name, but they don't take up quota. Why do you need to know what their size is?

Comment: well, some dox are 50+ pages, and others are 1 page. The dox reside in hundreds of collections (folders) and are in use by 4 different teams (with a potential audience count of hundreds)...it would help readership identify "the doc" they want to read or update. For 1. For 2, size IS available for Word .docx that are on the Google drive--if the API documented getOwner and getSize...with an example as well as contraindications (don't use with)...that would be a great service.

Comment: Right, but word documents _are_ regular files. I'm suggesting that Google Docs ones aren't - they're placeholders for the document in Google Docs, but they don't have a canonical representation. Note that if you try and download one, you can't do it without converting it to an external representation. How would knowing the file size help your users?

Answer (score 1):

As Nick Johnson said in the comments, this is working as intended. In the Google Drive UI if you sort by "Quota used" you'll see that Google Docs and Spreadsheets don't have a file size.

Comment: I'm the user. I've inherited a lot of replicated content: documents that a TEAM of 30 people had saved on hard drives and in CVS, often with different file names, different save dates, and different owners--and even multiple save dates by the same owner. Oh, and .pdf, .doc, and .docx formats...up to 10 copies of the same doc from one person...and there are 30 people who did this: they uploaded that content to google docs.